# flask-dance logout showing none-type is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, flask-login, flask-dance

I want to delete the token and session for the logged in user, so that when the user again try to login it will show him google login page again. I followed the flask-dance document. But when I am trying to logout it is showing None type is not subscriptable, and it is also not deleting the session. Below you find a snippet of my code.

```
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(client_id='',
                                         client_secret='', offline=True,
                                         scope=['profile', 'email'])
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint, url_prefix='/login')

@app.route('/login')
def google_login():

    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('google.login'))

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(google_blueprint)
def logged_in(blueprint, token):
    if not token:
        flash("Failed to log in with GitHub.", category="error")
        return False
    account_info = blueprint.session.get('/oauth2/v1/userinfo')
    print(token)
    if account_info:
        account_info_json = account_info.json()
        Email = account_info_json['email']
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=Email).first()

        if user:
            try:
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
            except BaseException():
                return redirect(url_for('google.login'))

        else:
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():

    token = google_blueprint.token["access_token"] #showing error in this line
    resp = google.post(
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke",
        params={"token": token},
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    )
    assert resp.ok, resp.text
    logout_user()        # Delete Flask-Login's session cookie
    del google_blueprint.token  # Delete OAuth token from storage
    return redirect('/')
```

I get the error in the 1st line of the logout route. How to solve this?

Comment: Inside the `logout` method, could you print the value of `google_blueprint`. I think it will be `None`

Comment: it is showing error.'OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint' object is not callable

Comment: This happens because `google_blueprint.token` returns `None`

Comment: how to solve this?how to get the token and delete it?in the flask-dance documentation,it is mentioned like this only.

Answer (score 1):

If `blueprint.token` is None, that indicates that there is no OAuth token in the token storage system. Generally, this indicates that there is no saved token to revoke. If you have this issue, it might indicate that you don't have a logged in user in the first place -- it doesn't make sense to logout if you're not logged in!

See also [the docs for `OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint.token`](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_dance.consumer.OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint.token).